# how to obtain the eigenfaces using eigenvalues and eigen vectors?

Tags: matlab

i want to find eigenfaces from eigen values here is the code for reference.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

% I) READ IMAGES
for i = 1:9
    img{i} = imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\archana\target\' num2str(i) '.jpg']);
end

%II) CONVERTING TO GRAY SCALE
gray_img=cellfun(@rgb2gray,img,'uniformoutput',false);
%imshow(gray_img{2});

%III) RESIZING GRAY IMAGES
res_img = cellfun(@(x)(imresize(x, [50, 50])), gray_img, 'UniformOutput', false);
%imshow(res_img{2});

%DISPLAYING ALL IMAGE
    D=[res_img{1} res_img{2} res_img{3}
        res_img{4} res_img{5} res_img{6}
        res_img{7} res_img{8} res_img{9}];
   figure, imshow(D);

%MEAN IMAGE 
mean_img=(res_img{1}+res_img{2}+res_img{3}+res_img{4}+res_img{5}+res_img{6}+res_img{7}+res_img{8}+res_img{9})/9;
figure,imshow(mean_img);

%III)SINGLE VECTOR CONVERSION
vect_img= cellfun(@(x)((x(:))), res_img, 'UniformOutput', false);

%MEAN OF SINGLE VECTOR
mean_vect=(vect_img{1}+vect_img{2}+vect_img{3}+vect_img{4}+vect_img{5}+vect_img{6}+vect_img{7}+vect_img{8}+vect_img{9})/9;

%DEVIATION MATRIX
dev_mat=cellfun(@(x) ((x)-mean_vect),vect_img,'uniformoutput',false);
%imshow(dev_mat{1})
U=[dev_mat{1} dev_mat{2} dev_mat{3} dev_mat{4} dev_mat{5} dev_mat{6} dev_mat{7} dev_mat{8} dev_mat{9} ]
figure ,imshow(U);

%COVARIENCE MATRIX
C=[double(U')*double(U)]/9;

%VARIENCE
v=var(C);

%EIGEN VALUES
lambda = eig(C);
[V,D] = eig(C) ;% eigenvalues (D) & eigenvectors (V),=> A*V = V*D
size(lambda);
% EXTRACT DIONAL OF MATRIX VECTOR
%V = diag(V);

%SORT VARIENCE ACC.DECREASING ORDER
sort(lambda,'descend');
```

i reached upto the arranging the eiganvalues into non-increasing order plz help me how to procced in order to get the eigenfaces.regards

Comment: "its showing the error" What error? Post it. Also please consider adding a tag for whatever language/environment this code is for.

Comment: i am working in matlab  and error is::: Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 17%
> In imuitools\private\initSize at 75
  In imshow at 239
  In o1 at 60
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integer data types are not fully supported for this operation.
At least one operand must be a scalar.

Error in ==> o1 at 62
 cov(NEW)=NEW*NEW';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of loading each file one by one try this**

```
ImageDatabasePath ='C:\Users\shree\Desktop\final data';

ImageFiles = dir(ImageDatabasePath);

Train_Number = 0;

for i = 1:size(ImageFiles,1)

if not(strcmp(ImageFiles(i).name,'.')|strcmp(ImageFiles(i).name,'..')...

        |strcmp(ImageFiles(i).name,'Thumbs.db'))

    Image_Number = Image_Number + 1; 

end
end
```

**Now to make the images into 1D image vectors**

```
 T = [ ];

  for i = 1 : Image_Number

str = int2str(i);
str = strcat('\',str,'.jpg');
str = strcat(ImageDatabasePath,str);

imt = imread(str);

[irow icol] = size(imt);

temp = reshape(imt,irow*icol,1);   
T = [T temp];                  
end
```

**Calculates mean value**

```
m = mean(T,2); 

Train_Number = size(T,2);
```

**Calculates the deviation of each image from the mean image**

```
A = [ ];  

for i = 1 : Image_Number
    temp = double(T(:,i)) - m; 
    A = [A temp];
end
```

**Create covariance matrix**

```
L = A'*A;
```

**Calculate eigen values and eigen vector V-eigen vector  D-diagonal matrix with eigen values**

```
[V D] = eig(L); 

L_eig_vec = [];

for i = 1 : size(V,2) 

    if( D(i,i)>1 )

        L_eig_vec = [L_eig_vec V(:,i)];
    end
end
```

**Eigenvectors of covariance matrix C (or so-called "Eigenfaces") can be recovered from L's eiegnvectors.**

```
Eigenfaces = A * L_eig_vec;
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but unfortunatly its again showing the following error repeatedly i am new to this matlab so really cnt understand how to fix it please guide me regards the error is : ??? Error: File: o2.m Line: 14 Column: 1
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: Make sure all brackets have been closed and all end statements have been accounted for.

Comment: i banlced it but stil its not getting fixed...:(

Comment: hello i tried as u had suggested but unfortunately it is showing following error as Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> stk at 73
Eigenfaces = A * L_eig_vec; and also plz tell me how to see these eigenfaces..regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `double(NEW) * double(NEW');`

Besides, do not use `mean` and `cov` as variable name. They are built-in functions. I guess you want `C = cov(double(NEW) * double(NEW'));` in the covariance calculation.

Comment: thanks,that error is fixed now but can you please tell me how to see those eigen faces? after covarience what should i do ?

Comment: [V,D] = eig(C);Columns of V forms the eigen faces. Thanks